# A probability distribution has values 0, 1, 2, 3, . . . with probabilities πk = c(e^−λ)λ^(2k)/k! for a certain c. What is c?

Tags: probability-theory

I understand that this looks similar to Poisson Distribution, but I am unsure how to apply the fact that the probability distribution has values 0,1,2,3...

Comment: A probability distribution should add up to one over all of its values...

Answer (score 1):

We calculate the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty ce^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{2k}}{k!}.\tag{1}$$
of all the probabilities, and use the fact that this sum must be $1$.

Note that $\lambda^{2k}=(\lambda^2)^k$ and
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda^2)^k}{k!}=e^{\lambda^2}.$$
(We have recognized the power series expansion of $e^x$, where $x=\lambda^2$.)
Thus we need
$$ce^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda^2}=1.$$
Solve for $c$. We get $c=e^{\lambda-\lambda^2}$.